# Why am i getting error when using groupbyfunction()?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\HP\\OneDrive\\Documents\\final_annotations.csv')

p=df.groupby(['img_name'])
print(p)
```

i am getting an output like this i am not getting table:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000028A9E35DB70>
```

Comment: groupby function returns `pandas groupby object` not `pandas dataframe`.

Comment: That's correct. [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) returns a "groupby object that contains information about the groups". You now need to append some function call to make it useful. E.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,1],'b':[1,2,3]})` and then I can do: `df.groupby('a')['b'].sum()`, summing col `b` per `1` and per `0` in col `a`. You can try `list(p)` to get an idea of what you have grouped: you'll see a list of tuples with first element being index of the group, second element the `df` associated with that group.

Answer (score 0):

It can give you the output in a dataframe.

```
p=df.groupby(['img_name']).apply(lambda a: a[:])
```

or

```
p=df.groupby(['img_name']).apply(print)
```

or

```
p.describe()
```